# How to delete document automatically when it matches the time inside firebase for flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to flutter. I am trying to delete a particular document when the datefrom field matches with current time. How and where shall I call the delete function? Note: It must delete even when the app is not in use
[image]

This is my current code:

```
getText() {
   if (dateTime == null) {
      return 'Select Datetime';
   } else {
      return DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm').format(dateTime!);
   }

deletetask() async {
     if (time == getText()){
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('mytasks')
          .doc('time')
          .delete()
          .then((value) => FirebaseStorage
          .instance
           .refFromURL('image')
           .delete());
      }
```

Comment: if you use for single user for a current user then you can call into the initState

Comment: means it will only delete when the app is opened right. I want it to delete atomically even without the app is open

Comment: then you can set cron job backend side

Comment: do u mean in flutter? Because i am not sure where to call this cron function inside the app. Or can we do this from firebase console?

Comment: you can set the cron in firebase console or any other backend side

Comment: it's only available on Blaze pricing plan though... Not so sure about switching to uncapped billing while I'm still learning

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you're looking for are scheduled functions and they are [documented here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions).

Comment: it's only available on Blaze pricing plan though... Not so sure about switching to uncapped billing while I'm still learning

Comment: Yes that's unfortunately the case; this is a paid-for functionality. You mentioned that you want this functionality to kick-in even when your app is not running; hence you either have to write a custom backend that integrates with your Firebase project or you have to pay for Firebase Blaze plan and have scheduled functions.

Comment: Keep in mind that there's a quite generous free tier for Cloud Functions on the paid plan. So while you will need to have a billing account for the project, you won't have to pay for your Cloud Functions usage until you exceed that free quota.